# Navigation via selection of collection-select dropdown in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, drop-down-menu, navigation, unobtrusive-javascript

I'd like to perform a relatively simple task of selecting a value from a dropdown menu, and then navigate to the selected item.  (I know I must be making this much harder than it needs to be, but here is what I have).

schools_controllers.rb

```
# GET /schools/1
# GET /schools/1.json
def show
  @schools = School.order(:name)

  @school = School.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @school }
    format.css
    format.js
  end
end
```

view/schools/show.html.haml

```
%div.nav
  = collection_select(:school, :id, @schools, :id, :name)
```

assets/javascripts/schools.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
    $('select#school_id').change ->
        alert this.id
```

All I can seem to access is the id of the css marker, not the id of the school.  Ideally, I'd like to navigate to that school using some variation of:

```
schools_path[selected_school.id]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.